# How to configure RSPEC to never run on RAILS_ENV production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was trying to run some test because of changes I did...so I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rspec`

which was something very stupid to do since **rspec** (the tests) were configured to truncate all the tables and this was exactly what happened on PRODUCTION !! and you can imagine the consequences

Is there a way to configure rspec to never run when RAILS_ENV=production so this can never happen to any one.

What other advice or good practices can be applied to avoid this kind of mistakes

**UPDATE:** I created a ISSUE for the rspec-rails team and they just commited a change that fixes this problem https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/1383/files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `spec_helper.rb`, before any `RAILS_ENV` assignment:

```
raise "Not in test" unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "test"
```

Answer (score 5):

In your `Gemfile`, refer to anything test-specific (like `rspec-rails` or `rspec`) in the group for environments `development` and `test` **only**, instead of on the toplevel, e.g.:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Then bundling without the development and test gems on your production machine.  Without the `rspec` gem the tests would not have run.  Add the `--without` switch when deploying:

```
bundle install --without development test
```

Comment: This would work if the command runs from the production machine but the developers can still use RAILS_ENV=production from any development machine.

Comment: So what? That won't cause the production server to get wiped out.